# ¿Como hacer una consulta para agrupar por rangos?

Tags: sql, oracle

Necesito agrupar por rangos este es el resultado donde quiero llegar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta que estoy utilizando es la siguiente:

```
SELECT org_account, COUNT(RESULT) AS TOTAL_MT 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE FECHA = '02/12/2018' AND mt_msc_addr IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY org_account 
ORDER BY TOTAL_MT DESC
```

El resultado de la consulta es el siguiente:

```
ORG_ACCOUNT     TOTAL
Gateway_G       34
WSMS            23
smsgw           23
VMSTRWI         22
sdp             22
OtaDMC          18
ocs             17
PcRf            15
MNP_icon        3
wapgw           1
```

Comment: Cuales serian los rangos? queres arreglar el query? en que base de datos estas trabajando? que tiene que ver php aca?

Comment: Los rangos son los que puse en la tabla de ejemplo, que se agrupen en ese orden, estoy utilizando PHP con BD de oracle

Comment: PHP es un lenguaje de programacion, y no se usa dentro de oracle, es el que usas para hacer tu frontend y backend. Vos queres que los rangos los ajuste oracle o php? y otro problema, es que no hay una logica en tus rangos, como sabes a donde va cada cosa?

Comment: Si entiendo PHP es backend, el rango tiene que ser asi siempre como lo coloco en el ejemplo. Se entiende ?

Comment: no. o sea.. son valores fijos? siempre iguales? mostras siempre lo mismo en cada rango?

Comment: Los valores cambian pero se mantiene los nombres

Comment: a lo que me refiero es, cual es la relacion entre los campos org_account y subtotal.. siempre es igual?

Comment: org_account siempre se va a mantener esos nombres el que cambia es el total, esos datos estan solo en una tabla no existe ninguna relacion

Comment: ok, podrias mostrar la estructura de la tabla total_mt.. hay montones de formas de hacer esto..

Comment: Solo tengo esos 2 campos en la BD nada mas

Comment: No entiendo que quieres decir por _agrupar por rangos_. ¿rangos de qué?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos usar tu query como base de todo lo que hagamos para agregar esa columna nueva.

Como no existe, no podemos agregarla directamente en tu query.

Llamemos a tu consulta A* (eso quiere decir que cada vez que leas eso, tendria que estar toda tu consulta tal cual esta ahora)

Pero podriamos hacer un union por ejemplo para generar la salida:

```
Select 'grafico 2 y datos 2' subtotal,
org_account,
TOTAL_MT 
from (A*)
where org_account In ('OtaDMC','otarca1')
UNION
Select 'grafico 3 y datos 3' subtotal,
org_account,
TOTAL_MT 
from (A*)
where org_account In ('Gateway_G','MNP_icon'.....)
UNION .....
```

Fijate que hay que completarla donde estan los puntos suspensivos.

Tambien, podriamos usar un case

```
Select 
    Case org_account 
        when 'OtaDMC' then 'grafico 2 y datos 2'
        when 'otarca1' then 'grafico 2 y datos 2'
        when 'Gateway_G' then 'grafico 3 y datos 3'
        when 'MNP_icon' then 'grafico 3 y datos 3'
        when .......
    end subtotal
    org_account,
    TOTAL_MT 
from (A*)
```

Donde tambien tendrias que completar los puntos suspensivos.

Todo esto seria mas facil, si tus rangos ya estuvieran definidos en otra tabla, y solo ajustarias los mismos usan un join. Pero como decis que tu tabla no tiene ni un id, seria mas complejo..

Aunque la recomendacion seria crear una tabla

```
Rango                nombre_dato
grafico 2 y datos 2  OtaDMC
grafico 2 y datos 2  otarca1
```

Y luego, con eso, solo harias un join entre tu consulta y esta tabla de la siguiente forma:

```
Select Rango, org_account, Total_MT
From (A*) inner join nuevatabla on nombre_dato = org_account
```

Answer (score 0):

basicamente en tu misma
pregunta te estas respondiendo, te muestro:

`SELECT org_account, COUNT(RESULT) AS TOTAL_MT 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE FECHA = '02/12/2018' AND mt_msc_addr IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY org_account 
HAVING COUNT(RESULT) BETWEEN 15 AND 23
ORDER BY TOTAL_MT DESC`

nota: no pude ver tu imagen, asi que con los primeros comentarios creo que comprendi, espero te sirva...